# Recover Id or Value with PHP/JS/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm working on a project and I need to recover Id in php or js

I have 2 row in the same table (mySql) row 1 = id_answer and row 2 = text

I exploit the first row text with a foreach in my code.

I search to associate in the same time in a div, my text and in value the Id who doing references to this answer.

```
<ul id="listQuestionResponseFaq" class="col-sm-12 pad-0">

<?php 
   foreach ($questionResponseArrayFaq as $questionResponseFaq ) {
    ?>
     <li class="liSearchFaq col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 pad-0">
       <div class='panel padding txtLeft' value="<?php $answerSearch ?> ">
         <?php echo $questionResponseFaq; ?>                   
       </div> 
      </li>
<?php
  } 
?> 
</ul>
```

I dont know how to recover the id_answer and insert in my answer. 
Its not the same id for all answer. 
Every answer got a different ID

Thx to help me

[MySQLBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MilkI.png)

```
$queryFaq = $pdoRepository->executeQuery("
SELECT DISTINCT fa.* FROM form_answer AS fa
LEFT JOIN form_option_filter AS fof
ON fof.id_option = fa.id_option
LEFT JOIN form_option AS fo
ON fo.id_option = fa.id_option
WHERE fof.statut = 1
AND fo.search = 1");

if ($queryFaq) {
$questionResponseArrayFaq = array();
while ($row = $queryFaq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {     
    $questionsSearch = $row['text'];
    $answerSearch = $row['id_answer'];

    array_push($questionResponseArrayFaq, $questionsSearch);        

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please include a more detailed explanation of the database structure. Perhaps a table with some example data in it would help.

Comment: OK I will show you more code, thx

Comment: What does `$questionResponseArrayFaq` contain? Post the `var_dump`

Comment: the $questionResponseArrayFaq is the name of my array
I push only my answer in the array and i loop her for echo all the answer
Maybe I need to add my id_answer in the array ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are looking for and if so I am going to recomend you take a different approach to take advantage of PHP's associate array looping.

```
$questions = array();
while ($row = $queryFaq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $questions[$row['text']] = $row['id_answer'];
}

foreach($questions as $question => $answer)
{
  echo 'Question: ' . sanitize($question);
  echo 'Answer:' . sanitize($answer);
}
```

If you really want 2 seperate arrays you can itterate through both using the `reset` and `next` functions. I found this on another stack overflow example a hwile ago but can't find it right now. If someone does feel free to reference and give credit.

```
$questions = array();
$answers = array();
while ($row = $queryFaq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $questions[] = $row['text']
    $answers[] = $row['id_answer'];
}

$answer = reset($answers);
foreach($questions as $question)
{
  echo 'Question: ' . sanitize($question);
  echo 'Answer:' . sanitize($answer);
  $answer = next($answers);
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly the result of what i need. Because i need something like that

     <div value =" <?php echo $answerId ?>">

         <?php echo $questionResponseFaq; ?>

    </div>

Then, in js i can isolate this value for condition him. 
Because after that, I will doing a condition for dont duplicate the answers. Then I need to capture this id_answer

Comment: @khyra It's not meant to be the exact answer. It's a generalized version of the solution so that the answer is more useful to others. You will need to understand my answer and apply the concepts to your code.